# Unable to use timeshift after btrfs installation

Tags: btrfs, timeshift

I just installed Ubuntu 23.04 with btrfs installation
the point i do not think everything went great indeed I think the btrfs subvolumes are missing and i do not know how to fix this without losing data

At first I executed

```
sudo btrfs subvolume list /
```

and the output was none, then

```
sudo  btrfs sub snap / /@
```

I executed this since i was following a topic quite old on here and now i have

```
mich@xps-15-7590:~$ sudo btrfs subvolume list /
ID 256 gen 9956 top level 5 path @
```

In the picture is written:
"Unsupported"
" system partition has a secondary volume layout that is not supported. Only layout with ubuntu-type with @ and subvolumes @home are supported "

I do not really know how to go on now or if i should format everything

thank you all

[image: timeshift]

Comment: Hello, I tought was quite obvious plus this issue is not so related to ubuntu version, can be ubuntu 22 if you wish or even ubuntu 18. Trying to keep this as less off topic as possible here you are `mich@xps-15-7590:~$ lsb_release -rd
No LSB modules are available.
Description: Ubuntu 23.04
Release: 23.04
mich@xps-15-7590:~$ uname -r
6.2.0-34-generic`. Really I did not think there were people getting offended by "april" missing